# ImageMagick fails to install on Raspbian Jesse v4.9

Tags: installation, raspberry-pi, imagemagick, raspbian

For 2 days now I have been trying to install ImageMagick on Raspbian Jesse (4.9)  No matter the advice I have followed, I just can't get it to install, always failing with the following:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  ghostscript imagemagick-6.q16 imagemagick-common libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libgs9 libgs9-common libijs-0.35 libjbig2dec0 liblqr-1-0
  libmagickcore-6.q16-2 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-2 libnetpbm10 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libwmf0.2-7 netpbm
Suggested packages:
  ghostscript-x imagemagick-doc autotrace enscript ffmpeg gimp gnuplot grads graphviz hp2xx html2ps libwmf-bin mplayer povray radiance
  sane-utils texlive-base-bin transfig ufraw-batch inkscape
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ghostscript imagemagick imagemagick-6.q16 imagemagick-common libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21 libgs9 libgs9-common libijs-0.35 libjbig2dec0
  liblqr-1-0 libmagickcore-6.q16-2 libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-2 libnetpbm10 libpaper-utils libpaper1 libwmf0.2-7 netpbm
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 33 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/8,340 kB of archives.
After this operation, 27.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package imagemagick-common.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'qdbus' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

There is no shortage of posts covering:

```
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

But no remedies mentioned resolve my install fail.  Clearly there is an issue with the `qdbus` files list:

```
files list file for package 'qdbus' is missing final newline
```

But I don't know how to resolve, and have not been successful at finding an answer on Raspberrypi@stackexchange, LinuxQuestions, AskUbuntu and even the Raspberry Pi forum.  Can I just hack the list and add the newline?  If so, how?

It's not a space issue, I have 24Gb of SD card space available.

I have executed:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Any guidance or help is appreciated.